# BigQuery exports NUMERIC data type as binary data type in AVRO

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, avro

I am exporting the data from BigQuery table which has column named prop12 defined as NUMERIC data type. Please note that destination format is AVRO and can't be changed.

```
bq extract --destination_format AVRO  datasetName.myTableName /path/to/file-1-*.avro
```

When i am reading avro data, using spark it is not able to convert this NUMERIC data type to Integer.

```
--prop12: binary (nullable = true)
cannot resolve 'CAST(`prop12` AS INT)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast BinaryType to IntegerType
```

Is there any way i can specify prop12 should be exported as Integer while doing bq extract?

OR

If it is not possible during bq export, am i left with only option of reading the binary data in spark?

Comment: Have you considered converting the numeric to int64 (if allowable; value doesn't exceed the int range and does not have any decimal digits) and saving it in another table then use that table to export to AVRO?

Comment: @Christopher, saving it another table using int64, float are not options for me as we have other properties which are having decimals. I simplified the question referring to Integer only.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way i can specify prop12 should be exported as Integer
>   while doing bq extract?

In the extract command you can't do it. You can create a new temporary table and then extract it:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql '

    CREATE TABLE `my_dataset.my_temp_table`
    OPTIONS(
          expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
    ) AS
    SELECT * REPLACE (CAST(prop12 AS INT64) AS prop12)
        FROM `my_dataset.my_table`;

' && bq extract --destination_format AVRO  my_dataset.my_temp_table /path/to/file-1-*.avro
```

Consider that this will generate [additional cost](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#pricing_summary).

> If it is not possible during bq export, am i left with only option of
>   reading the binary data in spark?

[Numeric types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#pricing_summary) in BigQuery are 16-bytes, it could be possible to work with them as decimal. You can try casting them as [decimal](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#primitive_types) instead.